# Spring5 - Reactor API - Sending sequential requests and getting the responses as a String

Tags: spring, request, reactive, sequential

I am sending sequential request and trying to print the response as a string:

```
  Flux.fromIterable(keywordsList).map(i -> client.get()
              .uri("/hello?now-word=" + i)
              .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
              .retrieve()
              .bodyToMono(String.class))
              .subscribe(item -> System.out.println("item: " + item.toString()));
```

But this is what I am getting:

```
  item: MonoFlatMap
  item: MonoFlatMap
  item: MonoFlatMap
  item: MonoFlatMap
  item: MonoFlatMap
  item: MonoFlatMap
  item: MonoFlatMap
  item: MonoFlatMap
  item: MonoFlatMap
  item: MonoFlatMap
  item: MonoFlatMap
  item: MonoFlatMap
```

I tried to use FlatMapIterable, but I don't know how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, I am sending the requests in a loop. Here is the code and this works for me:

```
  for(int i = 3; i <= len; i++) {
        String searchStr = searchString.substring(0, i);

        Mono<ClientResponse> result = client.get()
                .uri(autocompleteUri + searchString)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange();

        String result1 = ">> result = " + result.flatMap(res -> res.bodyToMono(String.class)).block();


    }
```

But I would like to know the different ways we can do this. Here is the blog about this project:

[blog](https://ilakkmanoharan.wixsite.com/website/post/amazon-autocomplete-keyword-score)